# Is there anyway to upload file without submit button in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to give a edit profile picture functionality , Is there anyway to do this without submit button ?

Comment: what programming language are you using on the frontend?

Comment: Should be, like when someone click on the picture -> input to select new picture and onchange event -> upload the new picture

Comment: yes , it should be like that Alex . I am using ejs as a templating engine